# CreateContainerConfigError while migrating Kubernetes cluster

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, kubectl, kubernetes-secrets

We are migrating the K8S cluster to the new AWS region.

using the following command on Dev server which needs to be migrated:

> $ kubectl get secrets -n cog-stage -o yaml --export >
>   secrets-mumbairegion.yaml

on POC server in AWS Mumbai region :

> $kubectl create -f ./secrets-mumbairegion.yaml -n cog-stage

```
$ kubectl get pods  -n cog-stage  

    NAME                                  READY   STATUS                       RESTARTS   AGE
      keeper-68ff7            0/1     CreateContainerConfigError   0          44m
      bus-f954                0/1     CreateContainerConfigError   0          44m
      configservice-7gvg5        0/1     CreateContainerConfigError   0          44m
      fengsh-6fbc6bn8             0/1     CreateContainerConfigError   0          44m
```

Check the last line of this output is successful still why getting CreateContainerConfigError: Successfully pulled image "gold/keeper:feature

```
$ kubectl describe  pod keeper-68ff7 -n cog-stage

Events:
  Type     Reason   Age                    From                                                  Message
  ----     ------   ----                   ----                                                  -------
  Warning  Failed   57m (x20 over 62m)     kubelet, ip-172-Xx0-xx.ap-south-1.compute.internal  Error: ImagePullBackOff
  Normal   BackOff  52m (x41 over 62m)     kubelet, ip-172-X-x-XX.ap-south-1.compute.internal  Back-off pulling image "gold/keeper:feature_rouXXX_fXnd_online_status.6662.092"
  Normal   Pulling  7m14s (x175 over 62m)  kubelet, ip-172-xx-xx-xx.ap-south-1.compute.internal  pulling image "gold/keeper:feature_roul_fXnd_online_status.XXX2960"
  Normal   Pulled   2m15s (x188 over 50m)  kubelet, ip-172-XX-xx-Xx.ap-south-1.compute.internal  Successfully pulled image "gold/keeper:feature_roul_frXnd_online_status.XXX0"
```

Comment: did you manage to solve it ?

Comment: @mario yes got it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was resolved by migrating ConfigMap

## #kubectl create -f ./ConfigMap.yaml -n cog-stage